# Can't get WebElement tag name using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a popup page that I need to click a button on. The popup page is in Angular.

The button I need to click is:

```
<button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Apply</button>
```

The path the method calls take to click the button is as follows:

```
TemplatePopupPage templatePopupPage = editTemplatePage.clickApplyToClientsButton();
pause(5000);
editTemplatePage = templatePopupPage.clickApplyButton(EditTemplatePage.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <W> W clickClientSearchApplyButton(Class<W> expectedPage) throws Exception {
    click(clientsApplyButton);
    pause(2000);

    return (W) expectedPage.getConstructors()[0].newInstance();
}

protected void click(WebElement element) {
    String tagName = element.getTagName();
    String attributeType = element.getAttribute("type");
    if (tagName.equals("input")
            && (attributeType.equals("submit"))) {
        element.submit();
        return;
    }
    element.click();
}

public interface WebElement {
   void click();
}
```

I've tried a couple xpaths which all point to the button successfully, such as:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='modal-footer']/button[text()='Apply']")
protected WebElement clientsApplyButton;
```

It keeps failing at the line - `String tagName = element.getTagName();` in the click() method.
The error message is `java.lang.NullPointerException`

I don't think it's an issue with the XPath as when I inspect the page, the XPath finds the element on page. And now other element exists with that xpath.

I have a feeling it has something to with the **_ngcontent-c8** attribute, because I am able to click buttons on other pages using that same `click()` method

Comment: Apparently wherever you are calling this from, the `element` you are passing in is `null`. The problem would appear to be in that part of your code. However, without a [mcve], we could be guessing all day.

Comment: Can you add the line of code through which you are calling this click method ?

Comment: I've added the missing lines. Hope this makes it more clear, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can have a try:`@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='modal-footer']/button[con]")
protected WebElement clientsApplyButton;`

Comment: sorry some character is missing ,using this:maybe you can have a try:`@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='modal-footer']/button[contains(@_ngcontent-c8,'')]")
protected WebElement clientsApplyButton;
`

Comment: I gave it a go, but still got the same error. The xpath that you suggested did work though. It finds the element successfully on the page. Thanks for trying, I'll just have to do some more poking around

Answer (score 0):

i have a try in my IDE，it can work out.this is screenshot

[code screentshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVD36.png)